# AppInviteDialog android in hindi in most of devices

Tags: android, facebook-invite, facebook-invite-friends

I want to send my app invites from Facebook.The code I've written is able to send invites but I'm facing two problems.

1. I don't receive any callback after invitation.
2. In most of devices Invite dialog has default language Hindi([Click for Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljtXz.jpg)). How can I change the defaults to English?.
   PS: I have checked default language in my Facebook developer account app is English.
   Any help would be appreciated.

   ```
   String AppURl = "<My Facebook App URL>";
   String previewImageUrl = "<Preview Image URL>";

   sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

   AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(getActivity());
   appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager,
           new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
               @Override
               public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                   Log.d("Invitation", "Invitation Sent Successfully");
                   Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Invitation Sent Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               }

               @Override
               public void onCancel() {
               }

               @Override
               public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                   Log.d("Invitation", "Error Occured");
               }
           });

   if (AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
       AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
               .setApplinkUrl(AppURl)
               .setPreviewImageUrl(previewImageUrl)
               .build();
       appInviteDialog.show(content);
   }
   ```

Comment: Have you got any solution for it?

Comment: Do u find any solution ??? Aman

Comment: Looks like It's a verified bug from Facebook: [link](https://goo.gl/J5SHc8)